# Como personalizar o e-mail de recuperação de senha (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, email, laravel-auth

Como posso personalizar o e-mail de recuperação de senha do Laravel 5.4, preciso alterar o idioma mas não encontro o lugar para editar.

Answer (score 13):

Instrução passo-a-passo:

Você deve criar uma classe nova de notificação para sobrescrever o texto padrão da mensagem.

1. Para criar uma nova classe de notificação você deve usar esta linha de comando:

   ```
   php artisan make:notification meuResetDeSenha
   ```

Isso criará a nova classe 'meuResetDeSenha' no diretório app/Notifications.

2. Altere o construtor do arquivo gerado para:

   ```
   public function __construct($token)
   {
       $this->token = $token;
   }
   ```
3. Adicione ao modelo do usuário (provavelmente em app/User.php) a seguinte importação:

   ```
   use App\Notifications\meuResetDeSenha;
   ```
4. Adicione esse novo método ao modelo do usuário:

   ```
   public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
   {
       $this->notify(new meuResetDeSenha($token));
   }
   ```
5. Rode o comando artisan a seguir para publicar as mudanças.

   ```
   php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
   ```

Após rodar este comando, o template de email de notificação será localizado no diretório resources/views/vendor/notifications

6. Edite os textos em line e action do método toMail() na sua classe meuResetDeSenha

   ```
   public function toMail($notifiable)
   {
       return (new MailMessage)
           ->subject('Assunto do email')
           ->greeting('Ol&aacute;!')
           ->line('Voc&ecirc; est&aacute; recebendo este e-mail porque n&oacute;s recebemos uma requisi&ccedil;&atilde;o para sua conta.')
           ->action('REDEFINIR SENHA', route('password.reset', $this->token))
           ->line('Se voc&ecirc; n&atilde;o requisitou uma redefini&ccedil;&atilde; de senha, nenhuma a&ccedil;&atilde;o &eacute; necess&aacute;ria.')
           ->markdown('vendor.notifications.email');
   }
   ```

Isso está descrito em https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#formatting-mail-messages

7. Edite o texto do email em resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php se você quiser.

---

Apesar da maior parte ser traduzida de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327954/laravel-5-3-redefine-reset-email-blade-template , eu adicionei o passo 2 na minha resposta, pois precisei implementá-lo para funcionar aqui e adicionei o markdown no passo 6.

Comment: Precisa fazer mais alguma coisa, não envia o e-mail dá Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)... Tem algum lugar alem do .env para incluir configurações de e-mail.. tipo smtp, porta. etc... Obs. já estou enviando emails em outra view configurado no .env...

Comment: Até tem em /config/mail.php, mas não sei se está lá o que você precisa.

Answer (score 1):

os arquivos de tradução ficam na pasta resource/lang/
o arquivo referente as áreas de login é o auth.php você pode edita-lo como quiser.

Comment: Já mudei esses arquivos, eles servem apenas para a validação dos campos, o que preciso é editar o e-mail de recuperação de senha que o laravel envia.

Answer (score -2):

Acho que o arquivo é esse:

resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php