# Alterar templade de email enviado para resetar senha em Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, artisan, laravel-auth

Criei o modulo de autenticação da minha aplicação com o `php artisan make:auth` e o metodo de resetar senha é criado automaticamente por ele, ta tudo funcionando blz... o que acontece é que quero modificar a view onde é montado o email para enviar o link de resetar a senha, sei onde fica mas acho que modificar um arquivo do vendor/ não é a melhor maneira, como poderia fazer?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187331/como-personalizar-o-e-mail-de-recupera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-senha-laravel-5-4

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como personalizar o e-mail de recuperação de senha (Laravel 5.4)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187331/como-personalizar-o-e-mail-de-recupera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-senha-laravel-5-4)